# How to order a dataset according to specific column order

Tags: r, dataset

I have the following dataset

[image]

and I would like the order in the "Crowding" column to be the following: "Uncrow", "CrowGr", "CrowUng".

Comment: Please don't post data as images. Take a look at how to make a [great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for ways of showing data.

Comment: You can do `Params_data_long$Crowding <- factor(Params_data_long$Crowding, levels = c("Uncrow", "CrowGr", "CrowUng"))` and then `Params_data_long[order(Params_data_long$Crowding), ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple solution using `dplyr`.

I've created a dummy code there to test it. Would be best in the future to post reproducible examples though for people to answer.

```
library(dplyr)

Params_data_long <- data.frame(Crowding = c("CrowGr", "CrowGr", "Uncrow", "CrowGr", "Uncrow","CrowUng"),
                 Participant = c(1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2))

Params_data_long <- Params_data_long %>%
  arrange(factor(Crowding, levels = c("Uncrow", "CrowGr", "CrowUng")))
```

Comment: Hello Kodikai, Thank you very much, it worked!-Mikel

Comment: No problem @MikelJimenez, glad it helped. Can you mark the answer as answered? Thanks.